# Shifting a Pandas column, and then take the mean of the next 3 values (post_shift)

Tags: pandas, iteration

I have a dataframe, `df` which looks like this

```
           Open  High   Low  Close   Volume
Date                                        
2007-03-22  2.65  2.95  2.64   2.86   176389
2007-03-23  2.87  2.87  2.78   2.78    63316
2007-03-26  2.83  2.83  2.51   2.52    54051
2007-03-27  2.61  3.29  2.60   3.28   589443
2007-03-28  3.65  4.10  3.60   3.80  1114659
2007-03-29  3.91  3.91  3.33   3.57   360501
2007-03-30  3.70  3.88  3.66   3.71   185787
```

I'm attempting to create a new column, that first shifts the Open column 3 rows (df.Open.shift(-3)) and then takes the average of itself and the next 2 values.

So for example the above dataframe's `Open` column would be shifted -3 rows and look something like this:

```
Date
2007-03-22    2.610
2007-03-23    3.650
2007-03-26    3.910
2007-03-27    3.700
2007-03-28    3.710
2007-03-29    3.710
2007-03-30    3.500
```

I then want to take the forward mean of the next 3 values(including itself) via iteration.
So the first iteration would   2.610 (first value)  +  3.650 + 3.910(which are the next values) divided by 3. 
Then we take the next value 3.650 (first value) and do the same. Creating a column of values.

At first I tried something like :

```
df['Avg'] =df.Open.shift(-3).iloc[0:3].mean()
```

But this doesn't iterate through all the values of Open.shift

This next loop seems to work but is very slow, and I was told it's bad practice to use for loops in Pandas.

```
for i in range(0, len(df.Open)):
    df['Avg'][i] =df.Open.shift(-3).iloc[i:i+4].mean()
```

I tried to thinking of ways to use apply

```
df.Open.shift(-3).apply(loc[0:4].mean())
df.Open.shift(-3).apply(lambda x: x[0:4].mean())
```

but these seems to give errors such as

`TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable` etc

I can't think of an elegant way of doings this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pandas rolling_mean. Since it uses backward window, it will give you the first two rows as 2.61 (value itself) and 3.13(mean of row 0 and row 1). To handle that, you can use shift(-2) to shift the values by 2 rows.

```
pd.rolling_mean(df, window=3, min_periods=1).shift(-2)
```

output:

```
            open
date    
2007-03-22  3.390000
2007-03-23  3.753333
2007-03-26  3.773333
2007-03-27  3.706667
2007-03-28  3.640000
2007-03-29  NaN
2007-03-30  NaN
```

Comment: Ah. Okay, I understand. It was a little confusing at first, but it seems to work(after working it out) I'm going to wait and see if there any different answers before awarding the best answer. Thank you.

Comment: @moondra I'm catching a plane at the moment otherwise I'd give you a numpy answer. However, this is a perfect pandas answer.

Comment: Syntactically, I like using the rolling method instead. df.open.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean().shift(-2)

Comment: @piRSquared, I would love to see the numpy answer. SO has been such a great source for learning for me

Comment: @A-Za-z I've posted a `numpy` alternative for your enjoyment

Answer (score 1):

## `numpy` solution

As promised
***NOTE: HUGE CAVEAT***
This is an advanced technique and is not recommended for any beginner!!!
Using this might actually shave your poodle bald by accident.  BE CAREFUL!

[***`as_strided`***](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/)

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# I didn't have your full data for all dates
# so I created my own array
# You should be able to just do
# o = df.Open.values
o = np.array([2.65, 2.87, 2.83, 2.61, 3.65, 3.91, 3.70, 3.71, 3.71, 3.50])

# because we shift 3 rows, I trim with 3:
# because it'll be rolling 3 period mean
# add two np.nan at the end
# this makes the strides cleaner.. sortof
# whatever, I wanted to do it
o = np.append(o[3:], [np.nan] * 2)

# strides are the size of the chunk of memory
# allocated to each array element.  there will
# be a stride for each numpy dimension.  for
# a one dimensional array, I only want the first
s = o.strides[0]

# it gets fun right here
as_strided(o, (len(o) - 2, 3), (s, s))
#          ^   \___________/    \__/
#          |               \       \______
# object to stride --- size of array ---  \
#                      to make           memory chunk
#                                        to step forward
#                                        per dimension

[[ 2.61  3.65  3.91]
 [ 3.65  3.91  3.7 ]
 [ 3.91  3.7   3.71]
 [ 3.7   3.71  3.71]
 [ 3.71  3.71  3.5 ]
 [ 3.71  3.5    nan]
 [ 3.5    nan   nan]]
```

Now we just take the mean.  All together

```
o = np.array([2.65, 2.87, 2.83, 2.61, 3.65, 3.91, 3.70, 3.71, 3.71, 3.50])
o = np.append(o[3:], [np.nan] * 2)
s = o.strides[0]
as_strided(o, (len(o) - 2, 3), (s, s)).mean(1)

array([ 3.39      ,  3.75333333,  3.77333333,  3.70666667,  3.64      ,
           nan,         nan])
```

You can wrap it in a pandas series

```
pd.Series(
    as_strided(o, (len(o) - 2, 3), (s, s)).mean(1),
    df.index[3:],
)
```

Comment: Haha. Thanks for the clear explanations.  as_strided seems like an interesting feature.  I'm going to play around with that method and see I can digest your code more easily.